# Why this formula works just for 11 characters?

Tags: iphone, floating-point

I have a UITextField with number pad keyboard and on Editing Changed event I do this:

```
textField.text = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%0.2f", [[[textField text] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""] floatValue]/100.0];
```

This is a script found on a site and it works just fine for the first 11 characters, meaning that if I type 10000000000 it displays correctly: 100000000.00

The problem come from the 12th character.
If I press again 0, it displays 999999979.52
And again 0 in shows 9999999959.04

Is it something related with the float size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least, you're dividing a `floatValue` by a double- either try `doubleValue` (as Ben suggests) or dividing by `100.0f`.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using floatValue of a string for display purposes, maybe doubleValue will work better for you.